# Exporting data from MySQL into CSV in Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

```
import mysql.connector

sql = "SELECT r.sensorID, s.area, r.date, r.Time, r.waterLevel, r.redalert FROM sensor s INNER JOIN rainfall r ON s.sensorID = r.sensorID ORDER BY r.date, Time INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/rainDB.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"

mycursor.execute(sql)
```

I want to execute the above code in my Python IDE to export the data into a CSV file. The select statement works fine in MySQL workbench. However, I keep getting the following error when I try it in Pycharm:

```
File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/BIrainSensor.py", line 106
    sql = "SELECT r.sensorID, s.area, r.date, r.Time, r.waterLevel, r.redalert FROM sensor s INNER JOIN rainfall r ON s.sensorID = r.sensorID ORDER BY r.date, Time INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/rainDB.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Which I think due to the backslash n (\n) inside the quote. Is there a way to solve this issue or should I just find another way to export the data into a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `\` (backslash)  to escape the `"` (since you're using it to define the query string) and `\` characters.

Please refer to Python String and Bytes literals https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Example:

```py
sql = "SELECT r.sensorID, s.area, r.date, r.Time, r.waterLevel, r.redalert FROM sensor s INNER JOIN rainfall r ON s.sensorID = r.sensorID ORDER BY r.date, Time INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/rainDB.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'"
```

Or even better, you can use triple-quoted strings with the prefix letter 'r' to mark it as a raw string. This way you avoid escaping characters:

```py
sql = r"""SELECT r.sensorID, s.area, r.date, r.Time, r.waterLevel, r.redalert
FROM sensor s
INNER JOIN rainfall r ON s.sensorID = r.sensorID
ORDER BY r.date, Time
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/rainDB.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
"""
```

Comment: there is a high probability for a downvote to this answer... Why? Because, it lacks clear explanation as well as a minimal reproducible example. Think about it!

Comment: @mnm please let me know if I missed something

Comment: thanks for revising the answer. And yes, you've missed answering the Q in its entirety. The proposed answer still does not answer the Q asked by the OP. Your example shows only the SQL part? Where is the python part?

Comment: I've pointed where the issue is. The `sql ="(...)"` is the Python part, which I mentioned. I gave a clear solution (two btw) with an explanation. What answering I "entirely" missed?